Which databases natively support sum types?
I would like to use database for storing my simple sum type. Here is the model in Rust language:
enum Item {
    Heading { id: String, level: u8, text: String },
    Paragraph { id: String, text: String },
}

Which databases are able to handle it natively? By "natively" I mean that I don't need some hacks to encode it (not like in SQL) and been able to constraint it on schema (not like in SurrealDB, which supports union types, but has not proper typing for objects).

You should look at PostgreSQL - very flexible type system.
